# Pyinstaller not working: permission denied on base_library.zip

Tags: python, windows-10, executable, pyinstaller

I am trying to get pyinstaller to work, and so I've tested it on a very simple program:

```
print("hello world")
```

Once I try to run pyinstaller as follows I get an error about being unable to create the base_library.zip

```
>pyinstaller hello.py
127 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4  
128 INFO: Python: 3.6.5  
128 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0  
130 INFO: wrote C:\Users\kollbenj\Documents\Executable 
Creation\Simple\hello.spec  
140 INFO: UPX is not available.  
147 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths  
['C:\\Users\\kollbenj\\Documents\\Executable Creation\\Simple',  
'C:\\Users\\kollbenj\\Documents\\Executable Creation\\Simple']  
148 INFO: checking Analysis  
148 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent  
148 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...  
155 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...  
168 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...  
5950 ERROR: base_library.zip could not be created!  
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\winpython\python-3.6.5.amd64\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
```

*Lots of errors tracing down to this one *

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 
'C:\\Users\\kollbenj\\Documents\\Executable 
Creation\\Simple\\build\\hello\\base_library.zip'
```

I have tried using administrative cmd.exe, and I have tried using the full file name path to no avail. Please help!

Comment: Maybe check if your `C:` drive is almost full or if the permissions of the directory you work in are set to read-only?

Comment: huh I checked and it looks like the folder is currently set as read only. However, when I try to change it from read only it reverts back instantly! I'm not sure why that's happening...I can manually create folders though.